# Create a sentence containing keywords with a specific CSS with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I would like to form a sentence. However, in this sentence there are keywords that contain a specific CSS, according to a word dictionary contained in a JSON.

I don't know how to take into account the CSS of dictionary words and the rest of my sentence to display it correctly.

For example, I get a sentence with:

I have a problem with my network cable....

Problem being in my dictionary in a JSON file I want it to get a specific CSS. Problem should appear in red.

I can only display keywords. I don't see how to reconstruct my sentence.

```
        for (let i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < newDataLime.length; j++) {
                if (features[i] === newDataLime[j].label) {
                    console.log(newDataLime[j].rgba);
                    spanCounter ++ 
                    // Max 12 span by each line for ver
                    if(spanCounter == 12){
                        spanCounter = 0;
                    }
                       fieldText.innerHTML = fieldText.innerHTML +  `<span class="verbatim-dashboard__text__lime hide" style="background-color: ${newDataLime[j].rgba};">${features[i]}</span>`;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Features is a table that contains all the words in my sentence cut to each space. So it contains for our example ["I", "Have", "Problem" ... etc.]

And the variable newDataLime contains the keywords of the dictionary.

How can I correctly form my sentence?

I hope I have been clear enough. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check this alternative, it may help: https://jsfiddle.net/od8jtmkc/1/

Comment: II would like only the words in the dictionaries to turn red. Thank you for your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to **replace** the word in your sentence array, with the **stylized word**.

And then, when your array is fully computed, you'll be able to put it in any DOM element :

```
for (let i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < newDataLime.length; j++) {
    if (features[i] === newDataLime[j].label) {
      console.log(newDataLime[j].rgba);
      spanCounter++
      // Max 12 span by each line for ver
      if (spanCounter == 12) {
        spanCounter = 0;
      }
      features[i] = `<span class="verbatim-dashboard__text__lime hide" style="background-color: ${newDataLime[j].rgba};">${features[i]}</span>`;
    }
  }
}

fieldText.innerHTML = features.join(" ");
```

Comment: Yes ! It's perfect ! Thanks for your help :D